# Object composition with overlapping behaviors

Tags: javascript, object, composition

This is going to be hard to explain without an example, so I'll use the one from [here](https://medium.com/code-monkey/object-composition-in-javascript-2f9b9077b5e6).

```
const canCast = (state) => ({
    cast: (spell) => {
        console.log(`${state.name} casts ${spell}!`);
        state.mana--;
    }
})

const mage = (name) => {
  let state = {
    name,
    health: 100,
    mana: 100
  }
  return Object.assign(state, canCast(state));
}
```

Simply put, we have a 'mage' object and a 'cast' behavior.

Now say that we want to have a new type of mage that drains opponent's health on a spell cast. It seems easy enough at first; just create a new behavior:

```
const canCastDrain = (state) => ({
    cast: (spell) => {
        console.log(`${state.name} casts ${spell}!`);
        state.mana--;
        target.health--;
        state.health++;
    }
})
```

However, this forces us to duplicate the original cast code. You can imagine that for more complicated behaviors this would be a huge problem. How can this be avoided?

If we used classical inheritance, the drain spell cast could extend the base cast and then call the parent method. But then we are locked into the problems of inheritance. If we add new spell casts, it would be difficult to mix and match them.

Comment: I think you need to use the `Command` pattern.  Have a method accepting an argument defining the spell to cast.  Then call that spell's method.  This way you have *one* method on your mage to cast spells, but each spell has its own functionality.

Comment: @Amy I don't think that solves the issue that I'm talking about. You would still need to duplicate code across all of the spell implementations.

Comment: What code would need to be duplicated?  The spells can inherit from a base class spell, you know.

Comment: Every spell (Command) object has properties defining their mana cost, spell category, a method to execute the spell.  Individual spell commands can have extra properties.  Each spell can define pre-cast and post-cast hooks.  Your mage's cast method checks the category to see if they can cast that spell object, deducts the mana cost from the mages mana, logs the spells execution to the console, then calls the spells execution method to do its custom behavior.

Comment: @Amy Okay, that makes sense, thanks. But the part I'm still not wrapping my head around is how you could mix spells together. If we had another spell that blinded the target, how would you compose a mage that casts a spell that both blinds and drains?

Comment: That's the Composite Command pattern.  A command that has sub-commands it runs.  The mage still has a single cast method that checks to see if he/she can cast that spell.  If it can, it calls the composite commands execute method, which in turn calls the sub-spells that make it up.  The Composite spell would inherit from your base class command, but its cost would be the sum of its sub-commands costs.  Likewise, its categories would be the union of its sub-commands categories.  Its pre/post call hook would call its children, and so forth.  You should only need one class for that.

Comment: Your mage still has a single cast method.  You're delegating the differing and custom functionality to each command.  Functionality common to *all* commands (spells) can either (a) exist in a base class for the spells, or (b) exist in the cast method before/after it tells the command to do its thing.

Comment: I can write an answer if you'll accept pseudocode.  I haven't written straight JS in a while, I mostly work in TS these days.  Or if you'll accept TypeScript, I can do that.

Comment: @Amy So that would require you to write a composite class for every mix 
of spells, right?

Comment: I don't expect so.  A single composite class can accept its sub-spells as constructor arguments.  It's all about delegation to the commands.  Each combination of spells could be defined completely dynamically, using the same composite, which simply passes off each property/function to its subcommands as required.

Comment: @Amy You can write a pseudocode answer if you want, but I think I'm understanding the high-level concepts just fine.

Comment: Okay, I'll write up a pseudocode answer.  If you wish to use that as a springboard for writing and accepting your own answer using *actual JS*, I have no objections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is given in sort-of JS **pseudocode**, because I'm not confident in my object-oriented JS (I typically use TS).

Your mage probably has a base class of Character, or something.  Everyone has a name and health, after all.  I have omitted that, as it isn't really relevant to the answer.  The question is about how your spells are structured.

I feel quite confidently that the Command pattern is what you need.

Mage has a few properties, and two methods for casting.  The first determines if the mage can cast that spell.  You can have spells have a category (or spell school), or however you want to check permissions.

The methods for pre-cast and post-cast, while not explicitly part of your question, will likely come up.  Maybe the spell needs to check if the target is valid *before* calling its casting method.

```
class Mage {
    mana: number;
    health: number;
    name: string;

    canCast(spell) {
        // check if the mage knows the spell, or knows the school of magic, or whatever.
        // can also check that the mage has the mana, though since this is common to every cast and doesn't vary, that can be moved into the actual cast method.

        // return true/false
        // this method can vary as needed
    }

    // should be the same for all mages.
    // we call the spells pre-cast hooks before casting, for composite spells this ensures each sub-spell pre-hook is called before any of the spells
    // are cast.  This hook can be used to verify the spell *can* be cast (e.g. you have enough health)
    cast(spell, target) {
        if (spell.getCost() > mana) {
            // not enough mana.
            // this isn't part of canCast, because this applies to every mage, and canCast can vary.
            // return or throw an error
        }
        console.log("Casting....");

        if (!spell.preCast(this, target)) {
            // maybe the target isn't valid for this spell?
            // we do this before *any* spells are cast, so if one of them is not valid, 
            // there's nothing to "roll back" or "undo".
            // either throw an error or return.  either way, don't continue casting.
        }
        spell.cast(this, target);
        spell.postCast(this, target); 

        this.deductMana(spell.getCost());
        console.log("Done casting.  Did we win?");
    }
}
```

The base spell, empty of functionality but full of that thing called 'love':

```
class Spell {
    getName(): string;
    getCost(): number;

    preCast(target, caster, etc.) {}
    cast(target, caster, etc.) {}
    postCast(target, caster, etc.) {}       
}
```

Your composite spells.  One class should let you do any number of combinations, unless you need something very specialized.  For example, combining two fire spells might amplify the damage while reducing the total mana cost.  That would necessitate a special composite spell, `SynergizingCompositeSpell` maybe?

```
class CompositeSpell : Spell {
    spells: Spell[];

    getName { 
        // return the subspell names
    }

    getCost (
        // return sum of subspell costs.
    }

    preCast(target, caster, etc.) {
        // call each subspell's preCast
        // if any return false, return false.  otherwise, return true.
    }
    cast(target, caster, etc.) {
        // call each spell's cast
    }
    postCast(target, caster, etc.) {
        // call each spells post-cast
    }

    constructor(spell, spell, spell, etc). // stores the spells into the property
}
```

An example spell:

```
class Drain : Spell {
    getName() { return "Drain!"; }
    getCost() { return 3; }  // costs 3 mana


    cast(target, caster, etc.) {
        target.harm(1);   // let the target deduct its hp
        console.log(`The ${target.name} was drained for 3 hp and looks hoppin' mad.`)
    }
}
```

The way this looks in use, casting a spell that drains health and makes my teeth shiny and chrome

```
var mage = ... // a mage
var target = ... // you, obviously
var spellToCast = new CompositeSpell(new Drain(), new ShinyAndChrome());
mage.cast(spellToCast, target);
```

The `CompositeSpell` constructor can check that the spells it is given are "compatible", whatever that might mean in your game.  Spells could also have a `canBeCastWith(spell)` method to verify compatibility.  Maybe combining `Drain` and `Heal` together makes no sense and shouldn't be allowed?  Or one spell accepts a target, but the other does not?

It's worth noting that the `preCast` / `cast` / `postCast` methods should take the same arguments, even if they're not always needed.  You're using a one-size-fits-all sort of pattern, so you need to include everything any spell might need.  I imagine that list is limited to:

- the caster
- the target(s)
- the area (for area of effect spells)
- options for the spell (in Dungeons and Dragons, the caster chooses what to Polymorph someone into)

One thing I'd like to point out is that instead of directly using addition/subtraction with your health or mana (e.g. `state.mana--`), use a function call instead (e.g. `state.useMana(1)`.  This keeps your options open with future development.

What if, for example, your mage has an ability that *triggers* when his/her health is reduced?  The spell doesn't know it should trigger anything.  That's up to the character.  This also lets you override the method, something you can't do with simple addition/subtraction.

I hope this answer helps.

Comment: For the record, the mage/spell concept was just a simple example for a much more complicated problem I'm working on. Although the concept of composite spells is fairly interesting...

This does help a lot though, thanks. I think this is the solution I was grasping at but couldn't fully form.

Comment: Either way, these concepts are broadly applicable.  It's the Command *pattern*, after all :)